# react-native-image-picker: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'yoga.YGNode', error on IOS (XCode)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm getting this error when I try to ru my ios app, I tried everything I thought of (still new to react-native ios part, always been an android dev): removing node_modules and installing, cleaning and building again, npx pod-install ios...

Screenshot of XCode error:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10466480/226730727-d2cd2889-6ba4-4f44-86ad-cdc665a4d710.png

The error sometimes dissapears after I remove use_frameworks! but I need that line because I use firebase.

```
"react-native": "0.68.5",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.1.0",
```

My pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
#$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'wooapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  #use_frameworks!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'wooappTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  #use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        target.build_settings(config.name)['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
      end
    end
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Output of my system info:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.6.3
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 455.92 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 8.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.09.05.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.68.5 => 0.68.5 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I've been stuck with this for a long time.